# Powershell - DataRow to an Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the result of a SQL query which looks like this:

```
$result1 | get-member

TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name   MemberType  Definition                                                         
----   ----------  ----------                                                         
. . .
DATE   Property    System.DateTime DATE {get;set;}                              
FCO    Property    System.String FCO {get;set;}                        
LS     Property    System.String LS {get;set;}                                
TCO    Property    System.UInt32 TCO {get;set;}


$result1
#multiple lines similar to this
DATE : 29/09/2015 00:00:00
LS   : c-am1
TCO  : 8059
FCO  : 0
```

I need to get this into an array thus:

```
$Data = @"
Date, LS, TCO, FCO
[the contents of the $result1 object goes here under the relevant headings]
[example]
29/09/2015,c-am1,8059,0
29/09/2015,c-am2,5985,3
"@
```

This is so I can pass it to the `ConvertTo-AdvHTML` function https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2448-create-advanced-html-tables-in-powershell-convertto-advhtml

```
$Data = $Data | ConvertFrom-Csv
$HTML = $Data | ConvertTo-AdvHTML
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but can't find it. How can I do this?

Comment: Your `$Data` example isn't an array, it's a herestring.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to put your data into an array but then show an example of your data in a string. If you are doing this to follow the example on the link to ConvertTo-AdvHTML then it is an unnecessary step because you already have an array of objects in result1. All you need to do is this;

```
$HTML = $result1 | ConvertTo-AdvHTML
```

You just need to add to the above code any switches to ConvertTo-AdvHTML.
The first step in the example from your link was only so the author could show a self contained example.

Comment: Cheers, but `$HTML = $result1 | ConvertTo-AdvHTML` caused the script to hang. 
I tried using `foreach $res in $result1{..etc..}` to create the $data 'string', and that created the table, but 
with one element per row, each containing the number 58?
It was only when I added the `$Data = $Data | ConvertFrom-Csv` that it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The way I eventually got this to work was:

```
$Data = @()
$Data += "DATE,LS,TCO,FCO"

$a=0
foreach($res in $result1)
    {
        $ed = $res.DATE
        $ls = $res.LS
        $tc = $res.TCO
        $fc = $res.FCO

        $Data += [string]"[row:white]$ed,$ls,$tc,$fc"

        $a++
    }

$Data = $Data | ConvertFrom-Csv
$html = $Data | ConvertTo-AdvHTML
```